# Css Selector button click with selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to click on a button using selenium. My code states it is unable to find the `css_selector` with said class name. The class name has spaces in it, which lead me to use the `css_selector` object. When I try to pass the class name in the 'css_selector' object, it fails since the class name is a string, which is not callable. The website is password protected otherwise I would share the full code. This is what I have so far.

```
# Button I wish to click
<a href="#" class="btn btn-alt see-full-list-btn">See Full List</a>
# Once button is clicked, it changes to:
<a href="#" class="btn btn-alt see-full-list-btn" style="display: none;">See Full List</a>
```

What I have tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR("btn btn-alt see-full-list-btn")) # str object not callable
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"btn btn-alt see-full-list-btn")
# Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"btn btn-alt see-full-list-btn"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've mentioned

`The class name has spaces in it, which lead me to use the css_selector`

this is right approach, however you should also make sure that one

1. One should remove the space and put a `.`
2. `.` represent class in CSS.

So the below code should work:

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-alt.see-full-list-btn")
```

or you can even use it with the tag `a`

```
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-alt.see-full-list-btn")
```

or the recommended solution would be to use with explicit waits:

```
see_full_list_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-alt.see-full-list-btn")))
see_full_list_button.click()
```

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know I am on the right path. However, that snippet still triggers the error: 'str' object is not callable.

Comment: @JackArmstrong: Got the issue it should have been this `driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".btn.btn-alt.see-full-list-btn")`

Answer (score 0):

There is no necessity to focus on the element HTML after the click is already invoked.

As per the HTML

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-alt see-full-list-btn">See Full List</a>
```

you can use either of the following [*locator strategies*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

- Using *link_text*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT, "See Full List").click()
  ```
- Using *css_selector*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-alt.see-full-list-btn").click()
  ```
- Using *xpath*:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-alt see-full-list-btn' and text()='See Full List']").click()
  ```

Ideally to click on the ***clickable*** element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the [*element_to_be_clickable()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54194511/7429447) and you can use either of the following locator strategies:

- Using *LINK_TEXT*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "See Full List"))).click()
  ```
- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-alt.see-full-list-btn"))).click()
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-alt see-full-list-btn' and text()='See Full List']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```